# Ionic- ionic serve shows blank white screen Ionic- The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

When inspect page on chrome browser, console shows "The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored".

Note- Just created a default 'photo-gallery' app with ionic-cli.
Below is ionic environment -

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (C:\Users\use
)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.9
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.2.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.2.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.0
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.18.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/viewport-fit-issue/111538/10

Comment: Hi Tomas, I have already checked the above link but its not useful as iONIC5 project do not have  @ionic/app-scripts  present inside npm-modules so no way to update that.

Comment: Seems issue with Chrome v0.58xxxx as works well on Firefox browser .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related with Chrome v0.58xxxx as works well on Firefox browser.
Just upgrade Chrome version, will work.